# jquery ajax never works

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this code and it always end up with error block. I spent four hours on searching but nothing helped. I want to load HTML data from a URL

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://google.com',
//data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
dataType: 'html',
type: 'get',                   
async: 'false',
//contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
//dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    //xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
},
complete: function() {
    // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
   // $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
},
success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
    if(result.status) {
        //$.mobile.changePage("#second"); 
        alert("Change Page");
    } else {
        alert('Logon unsuccessful!'); 
    }
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action             
    //var err =  eval(xhr.responseText);
    //alert(xhr.Message);
    alert('Network error has occurred please try again! ' );
}
});
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Check your console. Any same origin policy error? You can't do any cross domain request like that

Comment: Im always getting this  alert('Network error has occurred please try again! ' ); I want to run this code as mobile Android APP and using mobile jquery for this and need to call URL from a web URL. Im fairly new to mobile jquery :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cross domain ajax doesn't work unless the server allows for it**. In this case Google does not.
There are however some plugins and tricks to allow this,
another option is to make the request server side.

EDIT: I found this, which might help:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-in-firefox-3

It's for firefox but Webkit and IE8 supports it as well in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

it is possible to load scripts and images from external sites but not html.

You'll need to scrape it server side